# Background Playback Of Audio Stream After Interruption, iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I Have an app that uses `AVPlayer()` to play a music stream from the web. I have everything setup to play in background but when a call comes in (or any other interrupt) the playback will not resume after the interrupt is over. To be specific if the interrupt is dissmised pretty quickly playback will resume but if I have a long phone call for example playback will not resume.
This only happens if my app is in the background as well. If my app is in the foreground when an interrupt comes in everything works.

I have my interrupt notification set up as:

```
func playInterrupt(notification: NSNotification) {
    var info = notification.userInfo!
    var intValue: UInt = 0
    (info[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as! NSValue).getValue(&intValue)
    if let type = AVAudioSessionInterruptionType(rawValue: intValue) {
      switch type {
        case .began:
          print("began")
          pause()
        case .ended:
          print("ended")
          play()
      }
    }
```

Using

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers )
```

Fixes the problem but then if I start playing from another audio source, they both overlay each other. Ideally I need my app to stop playback in that situation.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?